# The requested resource /storage/public/user_3/1594182600.jpeg was not found on this server

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

Why I can't display image in browser although in my directory there were images. The directory is right, and I make sure the image exists in `/storage/public/user_3`, but when I access it, response only showing error `resource was not found in server.

I'm using Lumen Laravel 5.7

here my code

```
        $response = $this->client->request('POST', 'API', $data);

        $image = $response->getBody()->getContents();
        $filePath = 'public/img/' . $this->getUserDir();
        $fileName = time().'.jpeg';         

        if ($result = Storage::put($filePath . '/' . $fileName, $image)) {
                $generated =  $model::create([
                    'name' => $fileName,
                    'file_path' => $filePath,
                    'type' => 'motif',
                    'customer_id' => Auth::id()
                ]);

                $gen = json_encode($generated, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

                return $gen;
```

I hope you can help me, any suggestion and solution will be very helpful for me. thankyou

Comment: try to `php artisan storage:link` https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem

Comment: @Jazuly I have. I got error `There are no commands defined in the "storage" namespace.`

Comment: You  mention three different paths: `/storage/public/user_3/`, `/public/user_3` and `$filePath = 'public/img/' . $this->getUserDir()`, which one is it?

Comment: @Jazuly There is no `artisan` command in Lumen afaik

Comment: @kerbh0lz i see, sorry my bad, not really check the question..

Comment: @kerbh0lz , I put `$filePath = 'public/img/ . $this->getUserDir()` because I have 2 image want to process, 1 for upload saved in `/storage/public/upload` and image response in `$filePath`

I mention `/public/user_3` just to shorten text

Comment: `/public/user_3` refer to `/storage/public/user_3`

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly you have 2 directories:

```
storage/public/user_3
```

and

```
public/user_3
```

You can only request an image from the publicly accessible directory (which is `public/user_3`) If your image exists in the 'storage' directory but you want to make it publicly accessible, you will need to make a symlink of `storage/public/user_3` to `public/user_3`

Comment: I'm already put that in comment, `/public/user_3` refer to `/storage/public/user_3`

Comment: sorry if I make you confused, but I have updated my question